# JS6 Writing regExp with first digit as value from other variable

Tags: regex

**I have to write a regular expression for validation.** 
I have `classroomNumber` as a integer value, and want the roll numbers to start with classroomnumber value as first digit. How do I write the `regExp` in such condition. 
For example: 
If my `classroomNumber=5`, then I need to ensure the roll numbers of students start with `5` as first digit, like `501,502,503,504,505...` and so on.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)... Other than that, it would be nice to see what have you tried thus far...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do it like so:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp(fN + '\\d{2}');
```

But you want it to start with the room number, so you would need to change it like so:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp('^' + fN + '\\d{2}');
```

EDIT

If you want your expression to match comma separated values, you will need to use something similar to the following:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp('^' + fN + '\\d{2}(,' + fN + '\\d{2})*');
```

Given something like so:

```
var fN = 5;
var regex2 = new RegExp('^' + fN + '\\d{2}(,' + fN + '\\d{2})*');
var rooms = ['1,2,3,4,5,6','100,200,300,400,500,600','501,502,503,504,505','101,102,103,104,105'];
for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    console.log(regex2.test(rooms[i]));
}
```

Yields:

```
false
false
true
false
```

The problem with your approach for the most part is that you seem to confuse the round brackets: `(` and `)` with the square brackets: `[` and `]`. The square brackets are used to denote a set of characters to be matched, in no particular order.

Comment: What if I want the numbers be a list separated by commas.
I tried: var roomNumbersRegex = new RegExp('^'+fN+'\\d{2}'+[','+fN+'\\d{2}']*); Does not work !!

Comment: for new RegExp('^'+fN+'\\d{2}'+[,+fN+'\\d{2}'*+'$'] ) i got the expression as /^1\d{2},NaN/

Comment: I tried:  **var str='^'+1+'\\d{2}'**  I want the regular expression to validate list of three digit numbers , each number starting from 1 and separated by a comma(,)  **console.log(new RegExp(str+'\*'))**  gives me **Error: nothing to repeat** @npinti

Comment: The expression also shows true for  **var rooms = ['501,102,123,104,905'];** which is not desired !! I tried  **var regex2 = new RegExp('^'+fN+'\\d{2}'+(','+fN+'\\d{2}')*+'$');** which is actually  **/^5\d{2}NaN/** and not desired as well !!

Comment: **var regex2 = new RegExp('^' + fN + '\\d{2}(,' + fN + '\\d{2})*'+'$');**  worked for me!!
thank you @npinti